# Tuleap - configuration of personal notification matrix

Tags: email-notifications, tuleap, event-based-components

I have configured the mail notifications in tuleap, the thing is that it sends email to all users of a artifact irrespective of their status. In the help document provided by tuleap:

https://tuleap.net/doc/en/user-guide/tracker-v3.html#event-role-based-notification-settings

It shows how to configure for each and every groups involved in an artifact, but I don't find any settings available in tuleap tool. I don't want users to get an notification for each and every activity taking place inside an artifact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because is was a feature in the old version of the tracker system (V3), and is no more available in the last version (V5).

I know they are already studying the possibility to unsubscribe to an artifact, but if you need more, you should bring the subject on the mailing list [here](https://tuleap.net/plugins/forumml/message.php?group_id=101&list=1)